# Presentation corrupted after creating in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am tring to create a presentation on the basis of an Excel VBA Application. This is necessary because I have pictures in one folder and need to code the picture file names onto presentation titles etc. I also apply a template to my presentation.

Now my VBA code itself works as expected, but whenever I try to save the resulting PowerPoint I get an error (error message "An error occured while PowerPoint was saving the file"... helpful I know). I can also not copy the slides I generated to a different file. I tried saving the presentation in multiple different format (macroenabled and not etc.) both inside and outside of my VBA script, but no luck. I assume that I am somehow corrupting my file in the code but cannot find out when this happens.

UPDATE: I now know the corrupting happens whenever I apply my template to a slide, but generating slides with this template the traditional way works. Have tried multiple templates now I get it every time, when I add a template via the VBA script. Adding the template manually works fine.

You can find my code below:

```
Sub Call_Powerpoint(languageselect As String, sectionselect As String)
'TO DO: Explicitly reference Workbook and Sheets everywhere, add language selection user form, add file selectors for picture folder, desired template (?), desired place for powerpoint

Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim myTemplate As Object
Dim newSlide As Object
Dim oLayout As Object
Dim StandardLayout, DividerLayout, TitleLayout As Object
Dim lastRow, RowIndex As Long
Dim nrCategories, CategoryIndex As Integer
Dim sFolder As String
Dim File_Path As String


'Folder selector for Picture location


MsgBox "Please select the folder in which all plots are stored."

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)  ' Open the select folder prompt
If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With

If sFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
File_Path = sFolder
Else: Exit Sub
End If




'TO DO: Let user choose DestinationPPT
Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.application")

Set myTemplate = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("filepath to template")

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

For Each oLayout In myTemplate.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    If oLayout.Name = "Body" Then
        Set StandardLayout = oLayout
    End If
    If oLayout.Name = "Divider Slide 3" Then
        Set DividerLayout = oLayout
    End If
    If oLayout.Name = "Title" Then
        Set TitleLayout = oLayout
    End If
Next

'To Do: Add Folder selector for pictures
Set newSlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
newSlide.CustomLayout = TitleLayout
Call TitleFormat(newSlide, languageselect)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List Of Figures and attributes").Activate
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
nrCategories = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(lastRow, 6)))

For CategoryIndex = 1 To nrCategories
    If InStr(sectionselect, "| " & CategoryIndex & " |") > 0 Then
    
        Set newSlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitle)
        newSlide.CustomLayout = DividerLayout
        Call DividerFormat(newSlide, CategoryIndex, languageselect)
        For RowIndex = 2 To lastRow
            If Cells(RowIndex, 6) = CategoryIndex Then
                Set newSlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutTitle)
                newSlide.CustomLayout = StandardLayout
                Call SlideFormat(newSlide, RowIndex, languageselect, File_Path)
            End If
        
        Next RowIndex
        'TO DO: check if slides have been added otherwise delete this Divider
    End If
Next CategoryIndex

MsgBox "Select the location to save your presentations"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)  ' Open the select folder prompt
If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With

If sFolder <> "" Then ' if a file was chosen
File_Path = sFolder
Else: Exit Sub
End If

'myPresentation.ApplyTemplate (myTemplate)

'close everything to maybe allow this to save


Set newSlide = Nothing
Set TitleLayout = Nothing
Set DividerLayout = Nothing
Set StandardLayout = Nothing

'myTemplate.Close
Set myTemplate = Nothing


'myTemplate.Close
'Debug.Print File_Path & "\Bankvergleich_report.pptx"
myPresentation.SaveAs Filename:=File_Path & "\Bankvergleich_report.pptx"

End Sub


Private Function SlideFormat(editSlide As Object, curow As Long, languageselect As String, fileaddress As String)
    'TO DO: Insert check if picture file exists otherwise stop slide generation
    Dim titletext As String
    Dim pngname As String
    Dim oPicture As Object
    Dim FileExists As Boolean
    
    If languageselect = "German" Then
        titletext = Cells(curow, 3)
    ElseIf languageselect = "French" Then
        titletext = Cells(curow, 4)
    ElseIf languageselect = "Italian" Then
        titletext = Cells(curow, 5)
    Else 'english
        titletext = Cells(curow, 2)
    End If
    editSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = titletext
    

    pngname = Cells(curow, 1)
    

    Set oPicture = editSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=fileaddress & "\" & pngname, LinktoFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=125, Top:=125, Width:=14.75 * 28.34646 * 1.5, Height:=7.3 * 28.34646 * 1.5)
    
    Set oPicture = Nothing
End Function

Private Function DividerFormat(editSlide As Object, cucat As Integer, languageselect As String)
    Dim titletext As String
    
    If languageselect = "German" Then
        titletext = Sheets("List of Categories").Cells(cucat + 1, 3)
    ElseIf languageselect = "French" Then
        titletext = Sheets("List of Categories").Cells(cucat + 1, 4)
    ElseIf languageselect = "Italian" Then
        titletext = Sheets("List of Categories").Cells(cucat + 1, 5)
    Else 'english
        titletext = Sheets("List of Categories").Cells(cucat + 1, 2)
    End If
    
    
    
    editSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = titletext
End Function

Private Function TitleFormat(titleslide As Object, languageselect As String)
    Dim titletext As String
    
    If languageselect = "German" Then
        titletext = Sheets("Titles").Cells(1, 3)
    ElseIf languageselect = "French" Then
        titletext = Sheets("Titles").Cells(1, 4)
    ElseIf languageselect = "Italian" Then
        titletext = Sheets("Titles").Cells(1, 5)
    Else 'english
        titletext = Sheets("Titles").Cells(1, 2)
    End If
    
    titleslide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = titletext
End Function
```

Comment: Try creating a VERY scaled down version of your code to create a Powerpoint with minimal content and save it. See if that works. Then slowly add your other content, perhaps one slide at a time, and see if the Powerpoint file is corrupted or not.

Comment: I would suggest you edit the file path so that you do not risk sharing personal data

Comment: >>  "but whenever I try to save the resulting PowerPoint I get an error."  OK, but what is the EXACT text of the error message?  And have you tried manually applying the template? Perhaps there's a problem with *it* that's corrupting your presentation.